# Converting Visual Studio .net 2003 to 2008 using c#

Tags: .net, iis

I am new to c# programming and am tasked with maintaining web apps written in .net 2003, 2005 and 2008.  I am currently updating a .net 2003 app.  I opened two files; an .aspx and aspx.cs page in VS 2008 to update them. The changes were simple, add a buttonlink to .aspx page, add event handler to aspx.cs file that calls a SQL reporting services report.  The problem is I cannot rebuild the code because I couldn't open the entire solution without converting it first.  I opted not to do this because I didn't want to chance taking the entire app down if the conversion failed (an I've never done this before).

I have .net 2003 installed (and VS 2005 and 2008), but when I try to open any versio of VS, the project won't open because IIS is supposedly not installed on my local machine.

My first question is, which is better method to achieve update of these two files to ensure they continue to work on the server? Convert entire project to VS2008 or get IIS installed on local and rebuild it using .net 2003 where it was originally installed?

2nd question: can I just copy the two updated files to server (without recompiling) and assume they will work?

I am puzzled why IIS is *not* installed and when I check the control panel all indications are that it is installed yet I get this error message: "Visual Studio .net cannot create or open the application because no web server was detected at this url http://localhost/appnamne. Make sure the web server is installed and running."

Comment: The iis issue is probably looking for a different (older) version. Re not wanting to break it - you have a versioning system, yes? If it breaks... Revert (or better: fix)

Comment: The solution for me was to remove iis then reinstall it from CD --then it was recognized by Visual Studio and I was able to open my .net 2003 solution and convert it to 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Now Current Version is VS2008 and Latest Version VS2010. 
If you will convert your project in higher version it will be automatic task. Just you have open your project using higher version IDE (VS 2005/2008) what ever you want. I prefer VB 2008.

.Net 2.0 (VS 2005) & later we don't required any IIS to run application via IDE (VS). Now a days most up server updated with VS 2010 (.Net 4.0). so you can edit your application using VS 2008 (.Net 3.5).

First of all convert your application using VS 2008. (For converting in VS 2008, Open your application Solutions using VS 2008 IDE).

Then after make change and deploy for your project.

Comment: Thank you Mrugesh.  As you see by my previous comment, I did as you suggested.  Once I got IIS problem solved, I converted solution to VS2008.